# Generate url with user Api-key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I need to generate a url in rails that has the user's api-key in it (`webcal://123@mywebsite.com/calendar.ics` where '123' is the authentication token for the user), so that the user can use this link without being logged into the app. How do I generate this url?

```
calendar_publisher_lists_url(:format => :ics, :only_path => false,:protocol => "web cal")
```

generates a link like `webcal://mywebsite.com/calendar.ics` how do I add in the api-key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:user` and `:password` options to add inline HTTP authentication information.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for

Comment: thank you for your response, but that is not quite what I was looking for. To be more clear I already know how to reference the api_key, I am just not sure how to actually get it in the proper place in the url. I know I could do calendar_publisher_lists_url(:api_key=>current_user.authentication_token,:format => :ics, :only_path => false,:protocol => "web cal"), but that would generate something like webcal://mywebsite.com/calendar.ics?api_key=123. However I need it to be in the format of web cal://123@mywebsite.com/calendar.ics;

Comment: Right. You don't pass `:api_key` as the option, but instead `:user` and `:password`. Read the documentation linked, and try it out.